# How to fix error in trying to implement Google Maps after updating SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

After updating the Android SDK, GooglePlayServices isn't working anymore. I went back to test a maps app I had and updated play services from 8.4.0 to 9.6.1 because of other dependency update requirements. I am using build tools 24.0.3, and Android Studio 2.2. When I run the app after updating sdk and syncing gradle, the app crashes stating that it is failing to find FirebaseInitProvider. Yet I am not using any Firebase utilites/dependencies.

**LOGCAT**

```
        10-12 16:27:57.509 15347-15347/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
    10-12 16:27:57.536 15347-15353/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    10-12 16:27:57.573 15347-15347/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    10-12 16:27:57.573 15347-15347/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4169ed58)
    10-12 16:27:57.575 15347-15347/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.curtrostudios.maptest, PID: 15347
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.curtrostudios.maptest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.curtrostudios.maptest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4848)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4440)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4380)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.curtrostudios.maptest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.curtrostudios.maptest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4833)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4440) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4380) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**TOOLS**

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1

com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1

buildToolsVersion 24.0.3

Android Studios v2.2 RC2

Asus PadFone Android v4.4.2

*No other dependencies are being used at this time.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- applicationId is already defined
- I've cleaned project, rebuilt, and run
- I've invalidated caches and restarted
- I've removed the app from the device, restarted device, reinstalled
- I've tried reverting to PlayServices 8.4.0
  Still nothing works.

I've searched Google and nothing indicates that Google Maps requires or relies on the Firebase API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use maps, it's better to use the split of play services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
```

if using Gps etc add also:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding firebase dependencies services matching to your play-services above your play-services dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```